# Does C have enumeration-controlled loops?

Tags: c, loops

**What I'm asking:**

Does C have enumeration-controlled loops?

Why do so many languages require the step size of an enumeration-controlled loop to be a compile-time constant?

Comment: Can you give an example of a language with enumeration controlled loops?

Comment: Could you please give examples with source code? The question is still vague...

Comment: Yes. A basic `for` loop is enumeration controlled. It does not require the step to be constant. Other languages might want to create the list of possible values in compile time.

Comment: @Not Saying Fortran does have them

Comment: In C, the step of a `for` loop can vary. But that could make your loop less readable, and you might use a `while`  instead

Comment: Thanks for the late accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As for 1.:**

Yes, it does. 2 Examples:

for loops can be "enumeration controlled".

```
for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
   //your code
}
```

while and do-while conditions can also be "enumeration controlled".

```
i = 0;     
while (i < 10){
   //your code 
   i++;     
}
```

On [this website](https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/courses/COP402001/notes6.html) you can find an article about the problems with enumeration controlled loops in C.

Talking about "enumeration controlled loops" is however a little dated, as they are usually referenced at as "iterative conditional loops".

**About 2.:**

I'm dismissing your second question as [too broad] for this context.